# Setting up Chrome Logger Using Laravel Isn't Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I'm trying to set up Chrome Logger to use alongside Laravel as detailed in "Easy Laravel 5", however following the instructions throws errors, and I'm new to Laravel (and not very experienced in PHP), so I'm not sure how to resolve them. We are directed to add a piece of code to the `bootstrap/app.php` file to use the chrome logger in the book.

The following is a screenshot of the error screen:
[image: Error Screen]

The following is the site without the code excerpt:
[image: Default Screen]

I tried requiring the `chrome.php` file using `require_once()` in the `app.php` file, but the error still persists. Removing the code excerpt produces the default screen.

This is the code excerpt:
[image: ChromePHP include code]

```
if ($app->environment('local')) 
{
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog)
    {
          $monolog->pushHandler(new  \Monolog\Handler\ChromePHPHandler());
    });
}
```

I expected to be able to use the chrome logger, but instead receive the aforementioned error screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add new channel in your configuration file (config/logging.php):

```
    'chrome' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\ChromePHPHandler::class,
        'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\ChromePHPFormatter::class
    ]
```

Sometimes you may wish to log a message to a channel other than your application's default channel. You may use the channel method on the Log facade to retrieve and log to any channel defined in your configuration file:

```
Log::channel('chrome')->info('Something happened!');
```

If you would like to create an on-demand logging stack consisting of multiple channels, you may use the stack method:

```
Log::stack(['single', 'chrome'])->info('Something happened!');
```

You can set new channel by default in your .env file

```
LOG_CHANNEL=chrome
```

or you can set

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

and change 'stack' list of channels (config/logging.php) like this:

```
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single', 'chrome'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false
    ]
```

After you can use log with all your list of channels

```
Log::info('General information log');
```

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 5.6 documentation.

> The configureMonologUsing Method
>
> If you were using the configureMonologUsing method to customize the
>   Monolog instance for your application, you should now create a custom
>   Log channel. For more information on how to create custom channels,
>   check out the full logging documentation.

Looks like we need to be on the earlier version for this to work.